# How to solve the equation $t = \sqrt{x^2 - 1} - x$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let the equation $t = \sqrt {x^2 - 1} - x$. Find $x$.

So I've tried the following:

$$t^2 = x^2 - 1 -2\sqrt {x^2-1}x + x^2 = 2x^2 - 2\sqrt{x^2-1}x - 1 $$

What should I do next?

Comment: what Kind of number is $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be better :
$$\sqrt{x^2-1}=t+x\quad\Rightarrow\quad x^2-1=(t+x)^2$$

Comment: I'll try that. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Note that $$\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}-x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2-1}+x\right) = -1,$$ so $$\frac{1}{t}=-\sqrt{x^2-1}-x$$ Adding we get $$t+\frac{1}{t}=-2x$$ Or:

$$x=\frac{-1}{2}\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)$$

Comment: You have mistyped $x$ as $c$ in the third display.

Comment: Yes, thanks. @Wojowu